# Logout function in node & express

Tags: node.js, express

I am wondering how to implement the logout function in nodejs using express and express section, the code I wrote is following:

```
app.get('/logout',function(req, res){
  req.session.destroy(function(){
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

However, when multiple user login, if one of the user logout, everyone else that login will be log out. Can anyone please tell me how to implement this correctly? thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

NVM, I found out that the problem can be resolve by using the destroy(sid, fn) method in session-memory module